# Can MSAL be used to implement SSO using the Certificate based auth on ADFS for iOS Mobile App?

Tags: ios, authentication, authorization, adfs, azure-ad-msal

Can MSAL libraries be used to implement SSO using the Certificate based auth on ADFS for iOS Mobile App (Native or Hybrid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/active-directory-certificate-based-authentication-ios
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/active-directory-certificate-based-authentication-get-started